# illegal string offset 'nom_banque '

Tags: php

Hello I have an illegal string offset warning i've tried all the answers that I've already found but it didn't work for me

this is my code :

```
if (count($tabBanque) > 0)
{
    foreach ($tabBanque as $key => $banque)
    { 
        if (strlen($banque['nom_banque']) < 2) 
            continue;

        echo "<li class='encadre2'>\r\n";
        echo "<strong>Banque :</strong> ".$banque['nom_banque']." - <strong>Agence :</strong> ".$banque['nom_agence'];
    }
}
```

this is the result of `print_r(tabBanque)`:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [nom_banque] => Foncier Direct [nom_agence] => test))
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Only use `foreach ($tabBanque as $banque)`

Comment: I tried that, didn't work

Comment: check each item in the `tabBanque` at least one of it doesn't have `nom_banque`

Comment: The code as shown with an array matching your debug output does _not_ produce this error.

Comment: I didn't have this issue until i upgraded to php 7

Answer (score 0):

For all those who have the samie issue, I solve it with adding :

`if(is_array($banque))` after the foreach loop

Comment: Huh... that doesn't seem right. `is_array('$banque')` will always return `false`. You must mean `is_array($banque)`. Seems weird anyway to have to test for this though.

Answer (score 0):

Replace with the following code and try again, it will work.

```
if (count($tabBanque)>0) {
    foreach ($tabBanque as $key => $banque) { 
        if (strlen($tabBanque['nom_banque']) < 2) 
            continue;

        echo "<li class='encadre2'>\r\n";
        echo "<strong>Banque :</strong> ".$tabBanque['nom_banque']." - <strong>Agence :</strong> ".$tabBanque['nom_agence'];
    }
}
```